# I`m new to GDScript and want to create a function that rotate the object from the point of position in the screen

Tags: gdscript

> func CameraRotate():
> var mouse_position = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
> var ray_origin = camera_3d.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
> var ray_direction = camera_3d.project_ray_normal(mouse_position)
>
> var target_position = ray_origin + ray_direction * 5
>
> camera_3d.transform.origin = camera_3d.global_transform.origin
> camera_3d.transform.look_at(target_position, Vector3(0, 1, 0)

Im Expecting to rotate my object to the position where i currently pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can confirm this is correct:

```
var mouse_position := get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
var ray_origin := camera_3d.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
var ray_direction := camera_3d.project_ray_normal(mouse_position)
```

Note: if your camera uses a perspective projection, your `ray_origin` will be the `camera_3d.global_transform.origin`.

---

So this line defines a point in space some distance along the ray:

```
var target_position := ray_origin + ray_direction * 5
```

Note: Usually we would intersect the ray defined by these variables with the game world.

---

This line is wrong, but might not be an issue:

```
camera_3d.transform.origin = camera_3d.global_transform.origin
```

Here you are mixing local and global transforms. Which will match if the parent if the `camera_3d` is at the world origin and has no scaling or rotation... In which case this line does nothing.

So either this line does nothing, or it does the wrong thing.

---

What I suspect you want to do is this:

```
camera_3d.global_transform.origin = ray_origin
```

As I said before, when the camera uses a perspective projection, those are the same, so this would do nothing. But if the camera uses an orthographic projection... Then this moves the camera to center the position captured from the mouse.

I'll let it up to you to decide if that is desirable.

---

Finally, this line should result in an error:

```
camera_3d.transform.look_at(target_position, Vector3(0, 1, 0)
```

First of all, missing parenthesis:

```
camera_3d.transform.look_at(target_position, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
```

But more importantly: there is no `look_at` in the transform. There is a `looking_at`, let us change it... And the line does nothing:

```
camera_3d.transform.looking_at(target_position, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
```

The reason this does nothing is because `looking_at` returns a new transform. So the way you would use it is like this:

```
camera_3d.transform = camera_3d.transform.looking_at(target_position, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
```

Which would do something, the wrong thing, because again we are mixing coordinate systems because `target_position` is global, so it should be:

```
camera_3d.global_transform = camera_3d.global_transform.looking_at(target_position, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
```

This should make the camera look at the `target_position` correctly.

Yet, you do not need to do that! The `camera_3d` has a `look_at` method:

```
camera_3d.look_at(target_position, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
```

And, by the way, `Vector3(0, 1, 0)` is `Vector3.UP`:

```
camera_3d.look_at(target_position, Vector3.UP)
```

---

Putting the code togheter:

```
var mouse_position := get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
var ray_origin := camera_3d.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
var ray_direction := camera_3d.project_ray_normal(mouse_position)

var target_position = ray_origin + ray_direction * 5

camera_3d.global_transform.origin = ray_origin
camera_3d.look_at(target_position, Vector3.UP)
```

And it is here when I tell you about `look_at_from_position`:

```
var mouse_position := get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
var ray_origin := camera_3d.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
var ray_direction := camera_3d.project_ray_normal(mouse_position)

var target_position = ray_origin + ray_direction * 5

camera_3d.look_at_from_position(ray_origin, target_position, Vector3.UP)
```

Yes, it is the last two lines combined.

---

I do not know what you mean by

> rotate the object from the point of position in the screen

But I know you didn't say you wanted to rotate the `camera_3d` to look at the target position, you said:

> Im Expecting to rotate my object to the position where i currently pointing at.

And I do not know what your object is.

But let me tell you this: `look_at` and `look_at_from_position` are not functions of `Camera3D`, they are functions of `Node3D` (`Spatial` if you are in Godot 3.x), so whatever object it is, it probably can use them.

Thus, instead of this:

```
camera_3d.look_at_from_position(ray_origin, target_position, Vector3.UP)
```

You can do this:

```
some_object.look_at(ray_origin, target_position, Vector3.UP)
```

Which will let this `some_object` (whatever it is) at its current position, but rotate it according to the mouse position.

---

Since we are here, let us do that ray intersection (this is Godot 4 code):

```
var mouse_position := get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
var ray_origin := camera_3d.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
var ray_direction := camera_3d.project_ray_normal(mouse_position)

var target_position := ray_origin + ray_direction * 100

var query := PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(ray_origin, target_position)
var result := camera_3d.get_world_3d().direct_space_state.intersect_ray(query)
if not result.is_empty():
    target_position = result["position"]

some_object.look_at(target_position, Vector3.UP)
```

Which will rotate the same `some_object`, but this time to the point where the ray from the mouse position intersect the game world.

Note: this is based on physics, so it is using colliders, not meshes. *Doing it for meshes would require reading the depth buffer and some other stuff, so I'm not going into that in this answer. 99.9% of the time, colliders is what you want (unless you are trying to do mesh painting or something like that).*